# Mask folder in url to file somewhere else

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way in .htaccess to have a url that looks like www.example.com/one to instead of looking for a folder called one and find the index.html file in it, to just server one.html in the root folder? I've been trying to search for an answer but I'm not really sure what that would be called if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# always serve one/two/three.html
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: If I wanted to make four different rewrite rules /one to one.html /two to two.html /three to three.html and .four to four.html how do I do that, I tried adding them all but only the first one works

Comment: Great it is working how I needed it, one last thing, on my local machine the site is under a folder in my htdocs called "/foldername" but on the server it's under a folder name called "/dirname" (hypothetical names of course) how can I have this rewrite work regardless of what folder structure is before it? Hope that makes sense

Comment: Just comment out `RewriteBase` line above and place it in whatever directory you have and it should work fine then.